# What is wrong with this answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128005/how-do-net-profilers-work/8132836#8132836), written by another user, (the link is for 10k users) was deleted, presumably for the "not an answer" reason.

Originally, it was a little short and so I edited it to expand it out into a full answer and flagged it to be undeleted however the flag was declined with the comment:

> The link is still there, the post was converted to a comment (not just deleted).

I don't understand, what is still wrong with this answer?  The method described in the article is a valid answer to the question, the answer includes a reasonably summary of the article and Amasuriel (who asked the question) said themselves in comments that this "is exactly what I was looking for".

How else should I modify this answer so that it can be re-instated?  You can't mark comments as accepted!

Comment: Hah I have flagged the same answer (after your edit), would be rough justice if yours gets declined and mine gets accepted :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time it was deleted (3 hours ago), the content was *just* a link. It was converted to a comment (thus deleting it).

This was then later edited (46 minutes ago) into something with actual content and context. I'm content that it is reasonable to undelete it.

When the flag was declined, it was **still** just a link; the edit came **after** the decline:

[image]

So in short:

- when it was declined, the reason it was declined was that it was still *just a link*
- however, now that it has sensible content, it is an actual answer

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the flag was declined after the edit.  Next time I'll make sure I edit the post before I flag it.

Comment: @Kragen indeed, the moderators *over-delivered*, but handling your flag (within 2 minutes!) before you made your edit

Comment: @Kragen I'm the one that handled your flag, and what Marc said is exactly what happened. Instead of just declining it with one of the canned reasons, I (tried) to let you know it had just been converted. Sheesh, this productivity is _killing_ us :)

Answer (score 0):

If the answer only contained a link, there is few that you can do to expand it; whatever you would add to the answer, it would be something you add, as nothing the OP wrote would make you understand what the OP meant to write.

In these cases, where the answer is already converted to a comment, it is better to write a new answer that includes the link already used in the other answer (and now shown in a comment), and add a summary of what reported in the linked page. As you were able to expand the existing answer, you should be able to create a new answer with the text you used for the existing answer, and the link used in that answer. You can also make a reference to the existing comment, as in "As suggested by […]."